# What is the proper way to setup integration tests in grails 2.5 using junit?

Tags: grails, junit, dependency-injection, integration-testing

With grails 2.2 the following code (which is an integration test for a GORM class) was working fine:

```
public class DbDeploymentIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase
{
  DeploymentStorageImpl deploymentStorage

  DeploymentService deploymentService

  @Override
  protected void setUp()
  {
    super.setUp()
    deploymentStorage = deploymentService.deploymentService.deploymentStorage
  }
...
}
```

When I updated to grails 2.5, this is now failing:

```
| Failure:  testIncludeDetails(org.linkedin.glu.console.domain.DbDeploymentIntegrationTests)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'deploymentService' on null object
    at org.linkedin.glu.console.domain.DbDeploymentIntegrationTests.setUp(DbDeploymentIntegrationTests.groovy:41)
```

The documentation (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/upgradingFrom22.html) states the following:

> Dependency Injection for Integration Tests
>
> In order to support
>   alternate JUnit4 test runners, Grails 2.3 no longer uses a special
>   test runner to run tests and integration tests should no longer extend
>   GroovyTestCase.
>
> This change requires that any JUnit integration tests that require
>   dependency injection now need to be annotated with:
>
> @TestMixin(IntegrationTestMixin)

I tried adding this annotation and it has no effect: the code still fails in the `setup` method. If I comment out `setup` and access `deploymentService` directly in the test method it does work. So dependency injection happens. Not just in the `setup` method. And it used to work properly.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10584

Your test should not extend `GroovyTestCase` but instead should use JUnit 4 style

Comment: Thank you! I guess the documentation is a bit confusing and if the migration involves converting all tests to JUnit 4 style, it can be a significant amount of work for some projects.

Comment: Indeed, it has been difficult to balance advancing the framework with supporting new frameworks like JUnit 4